# Raised UITabBarItem like DailyBooth

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I came across this: http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/, but I don't really know how to implement it into my app.

I have the UITabBarController as my app delegate, but I don't know how I can add a raised button item like in the link.

In my .xib file, I have the tabBarController set up with three tabBarItems. I would like to have the middle one raised, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: People put effort into helping you by answering your question.  Deleting this would result in them losing reputation.  If your issue is solved by some other means, leave an answer with your solution and select it when the option to do so becomes available.  This helps people who have similar issues and does not penalize those that tried to help you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The link you provide describes exactly what you are asking.

Comment: This was quite a long time ago, so obviously a solution has been found or the question wouldn't have a selected answer, I don't know why you brought it up again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do it in a NIB using interface builder - the post you linked to has all the implementation and code details you'll need, so if you're not comfortable implementing UI code programatically you'll probably need to become comfortable with it in the near future.

Alternatively, you could look at using an existing library such as this: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/center-button-in-tab-bar - but if you're having trouble with the blog post you linked to I'm not sure a library will be much help for you!